# Possible to use a range of Excel cell values as the x and y coordinates for VB.NET Chart control?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, charts

I'm using a set of values from an excel spreadsheet to create a line graph in my VB.NET form. This is how I'm doing it right now:

```
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim s As New Series
x1 = xlSheet.Range("A11").Text    
y1 = xlSheet.Range("K11").Text
s.Points.AddXY(x1, y1)
Dim x2 As String
Dim y2 As String
x2 = xlSheet.Range("A12").Text    
y2 = xlSheet.Range("K12").Text
s.Points.AddXY(x2, y2)
'And so on
```

Is it possible to simplify or make this process easier? And how do I make the graph so that the line starts from the y axis and not between the y axis and first interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And how do I make the graph so that the line starts from the y axis
>   and not between the y axis and first interval?

I don't excatly know what you mean with that but the following should make it a bit easier to fill the series

```
   Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim s As New Series
    For rowIndex as integer = 11 to 99
     s.Points.AddXY(xlSheet.Range("A" & rowIndex.toString()).Text, xlSheet.Range("K" & rowIndex.toString()).Text)
    Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Those 2 lines of code work brilliantly and save me from using 40 lines instead.

http://i1141.photobucket.com/albums/n589/zzzzzz123456/c_zps561ae48a.jpg

I want to have the line start from the y axis.

Comment: Removed comment. It works great - I'm just not thinking straight without sleep.